# Is server-side Paypal payment verification actually needed?

Tags: javascript, paypal, paypal-sandbox

In short, the question is whether server-side Paypal payment verification is needed?

Longer story, I have as back-end Scala Play and as front-end Angular7 that uses Paypal client-side API to trigger a payment using as baseline the following [client-side payment pattern example](https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/client):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <!-- Add meta tags for mobile and IE -->
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
</head>
<body>
    <!-- Set up a container element for the button -->
    <div id="paypal-button-container"></div>
    <!-- Include the PayPal JavaScript SDK -->
    <script src="https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=sb&currency=USD"></script>
    <script>
        // Render the PayPal button into #paypal-button-container
        paypal.Buttons({
            // Set up the transaction
            createOrder: function(data, actions) {
                return actions.order.create({
                    purchase_units: [{
                        amount: {
                            value: '0.01'
                        }
                    }]
                });
            },
            // Finalize the transaction
            onApprove: function(data, actions) {
                // >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> IS THIS NECESSARY? <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
                // use data.orderID to verify the payment on the server-side
                myPaypalPaymentRemoteAppServiceImpl.verifyPayment(data.orderID); 
                // add payment verification result code here

                return actions.order.capture().then(function(details) {
                    // Show a success message to the buyer
                    alert('Transaction completed by ' + details.payer.name.given_name + '!');
                });
            }
        }).render('#paypal-button-container');
    </script>
</body>
```

Then the question is whether it makes sense to grab the `orderID` and double-check on my server-side using the Paypal REST API that the payment was indeed completed successfully and that the payment amount was indeed the intended (without the potential intrusion of malicious clients who could alter the price or attempt other forms of vandalism).

Comment: Well... If you explicitely exclude potential intrusion of malicious clients who could alter the price or attempt other forms of vandalism, then, no :)

Comment: You should definitely validate the client's payment. It sounds like you have some type of server running already. Would the server-side pattern work for you as well? https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/server If you used this approach, you can verify the client's request is the intended amount when the request hits your `createOrder` endpoint (before you send it on to PayPal to be processed), so you can fail immediately and return that response to the client if it's a bad request.

Comment: @thmsdnnr I loved the convenience and the L&F of Paypal's client-side buttons, I do the order verification later on the server-side right before delivering the products.